# Split unbalanced GEO string on comma

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column `(location)` with lat/long geo coordinates. What I need is two columns so I split this column using this:

```
left(location, locate(',', location)-1),
right(location, locate(',', location)-1),
```

I've tried some different column types and also found an issue about trailing white spaces in a split while searching the web but it did not shine any light on this.

Columns are `varchar50` as source and two times `char25` as destination.
`MySQL version: 5.5.27`

---

The results are not consistent as you can see in this example. There must be a way to do a clean split on the comma.

***This is not ok, trailing comma at second string***

> Split A 
>   '52.37924601809355,4.87214179273601'

```
Result A
'52.37924601809355' and ',4.87214179273601'
```

***This is the good stuff, happy times***

> Split B 
>   '52.37924969798386,4.872048790064259'

```
Result B
'52.37924969798386' and '4.872048790064259'
```

Comment: Could be that im missing something, but just change the `-1` in the `right()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `right` command to

```
substring(location, locate(',', location)+1)
```

Otherwise, the resulting substring depends of the length of the second substring (following `,`).

The command `right` is used to extract a substring of *fixed* length.

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/311e3/5/0).